# Related Field List Filter Django

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to create a list filter in django 1.5 is related to my field so I can not use SimpleListFilter as in the documentation.

I need to do this for reasons of user permissions

i have this

```
class Stores_Contactos_Stores_ListFilter(RelatedFieldListFilter):
    title = _('Por Tiendas')
    parameter_name = 'store'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return (
            ('80s', _('in the eighties')),
            ('90s', _('in the nineties')),
        )

class Store_Contacts_Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ('date_create', ('store', Stores_Contactos_Stores_ListFilter))
```

remains unchanged lookups as if he had not cast any changes to the filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lookups method is noy used by RelatedFieldListFilter class in admin package, the **init** method set

```
self.lookup_choices = field.get_choices(include_blank=False)
```

I override the **init** method in my class

```
def __init__(self, field, request, params, model, model_admin, field_path):
    super(Stores_Contactos_Stores_ListFilter, self).__init__(
        field, request, params, model, model_admin, field_path)
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        self.lookup_choices = Stores.objects.values_list('store', 'store__name',)
    ....
```